# Regedit add keys and dword

Tags: registry, regedit

How do I add a custom key and a dword. For example, I want to add windows mobility center to my desktop, so I have to add the AdaptableSettings key and the SkipBatteryCheck dword to the Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MobilePC\AdaptableSettings builtin key. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that so first of all :
Open "regedit" as administrator

- In the Registry Editor, navigate to
  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MobilePC.
- Right-click on the "MobilePC" key, then select "New" -> "Key" and
  name it "AdaptableSettings."
- Now, go into the "AdaptableSettings" key that you just created.
- Right-click within this key, select "New" -> "DWORD Value," and name
  it "SkipBatteryCheck."

Hope it helped you

Comment: How will i write an .reg code.

Comment: @JadonJung Like this :

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MobilePC\AdaptableSettings]

"SkipBatteryCheck"=dword:00000001